# Universal image loader displaying different image

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using universal image loader in my Android app and it's doing something weird.

I have users and each one of them can have different image profile, what I noticed is that when user 1 replaces his image, the UIL seems to load the old one, when I do this,

```
imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + profileImgFile, imgview);
```

it displays some old image, but when I do this

```
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(profileImgFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);
imgview.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

it displays the new one.

My UIL setting is below,

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheOnDisc().imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).cacheOnDisk(true).cacheInMemory(true).build();
ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder( context).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).memoryCache(
        new WeakMemoryCache());

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
 ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

What am I doing wrong?

BTW, I tried removing all the cache settings you see above and it didn't help.

Comment: Similar issue here with AsyncTask loader and no cache.